# web service takes parameters can not be called

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services

I am calling a web service that inserts some data in the database using hibernate, i am just putting a button in an html page

```
<button type="button" onclick="testMe()">Click Me!</button>
```

where the testMe() method is the method that calls the database.
Here is the function:

```
 function testMe() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8084/RESTfulExample/rest/message/insertdb",
                    type: "post"
                });

            }
```

and here is the web service that inserts data in the databse

```
@POST
@Path("/insertdb")
public void printDB() {
        DB db = new DB();
        db.insert();
        System.out.println("Done!!!");

}
```

until now everything is ok and the web service inserts data in the database successfully, but what if i want to call a web service with parameters like this

```
@POST
@Path("/insertdb")
public void printDB(String u) {
   System.out.println("inside web service");
}
```

and for sure modifying the html page like this

```
    function testMe() {
            var params = {"firstName": "test", "lastName": "test2"};
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(params);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8084/RESTfulExample/rest/message/insertdb",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: jsonData
                });

            }
```

when i tried this and called the web service, the line that should be printed in the printDB function is not printed.
What is the problem in my code when calling a web service that takes parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your WebService `printDB()` that you are setting  `@GET` http method:-

```
@GET
@Path("/insertdb")
public void printDB(String u) {
   System.out.println("inside web service");
}
```

But in your `$.ajax` call you are sending `type: "post"`, so what you can do is try in your webservice `printDB()`, change from `@GET` to `@POST`.

Comment: I changed it to post annotated and edited the post but the problem still exists.

Comment: @Engy.Mostafa what error you are getting while sending the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your on server side you are annotating your methods with `@GET` where as you are doing the `Ajax` call using `POST` method. The difference is that with `POST` the data is sent within the request body, not as URL parameters.

So consider changing/implementing a `@POST` annotated method.

Comment: I changed it to post annotated and edited the post but the problem still exists.